# Постоянное выполнение jQuery кода

Tags: jquery, html, javascript, css

Есть такой вот скриптик:

```
$(function() {
    var h = $("#about").height();
    $("#about").css('top', -h);

    $("#about_link").bind('click', function(){
        $("#about").animate({top: 0}, 1000);
        return false;
    });
    $("#close").bind('click', function(){
        $("#about").animate({top: -h}, 1000);
        return false;
    });
});
```

Как сделать, что бы вторая часть (когда блок скрыт) выполнялась все время. А то макет резиновый и когда текст в скрытом блоке начинает занимать больше строк, то блок увеличивается в высоте и вылазит сверху. Вот надо бы сделать, чтобы он все время пододвигался. Вообще как то без понятия что и как делать :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Попробуй обработать событие `resize` и повесить на него проверку изменения `height` относительно `top` и соответствующие действия по устранению дефекта

Answer (score 0):

Для постоянного выполнения кода (зацикливания) используйте [setInterval](http://javascript.ru/setInterval).

Если вам нужно задать четкие "рамки" блока (которые текст не должен масштабировать), пропишите блоку стилевое свойство ["overflow"](http://htmlbook.ru/css/overflow).